# Solving $ \int_0^1 e^{tx}ax^a(1-x^a)^{b-1} dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral

$ \int_0^1e^{tx}ax^a(1-x^a)^{b-1}dx $

My approach is intended to bring it in form of a gamma function. I have tried the substitution $ x^a=y $. Then I get

$\int_0^1 e^{ty^{1/a}}y^{1/a}(1-y)^{b-1}dy$

But I am not being able to proceed towards a solvable form.

If I write the integral as

$\int_0^1 e^{t(1-x)}a(1-x)^a\lbrace 1-(1-x)^a\rbrace^{b-1}dx$

then it isn't quite fruitful too.

I want some suggestions from friends here.

Comment: This is harder than the Beta integral. You may consider developing $e^{tx}$ with Taylor, evaluate the Beta integrals and use some recurrence properties.

Comment: for $a=1$ this is a confluent hypergeometric
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_equation